# How can I enable key-binding in a temporary-buffer?

Tags: org-mode, buffers

I have a large number of org files that are created to store some specific information, that wont change. I am trying to create a function to go find that file and insert it into a temporary buffer so that I can view it, but making it dissappear when I hit "q" like a temp buffer. The functionality That I want is `special-mode` but the problem is that when I enable `special-mode` I lose the syntax-highlighting of `org-mode`, and when I enabled `org-mode` it overwrites the keybindings that I need for `special-mode` to quit easily. My current solution would be to bind the key for `(quit-window)` to "q" manually, but I dont know how to do that only for this temporary window, and not for the shared `org-mode` buffers that I might have open at the same time.

```
(let ((bufferName "*Temp Buffer*"))
  (get-buffer-create bufferName)
  (switch-to-buffer-other-window bufferName)
  (insert-file-contents "file-that-i-want-to-insert.org")
  (mygroup/minor-special-mode) ;; Originally was (special-mode)
  (org-mode)
  (outline-show-all))
```

SOLVED

As per the accepted answer below I created a minor mode and that allowed me to override the "q" binding from org-mode.

*NOTE* I had to restart my emacs for this to work properly, otherwise it was keeping the `org-mode` binding for q even with the minor mode enabled.

This was the minor mode I created for anyone needing the same solution:

```
(define-minor-mode mygroup/minor-special-mode
    "Toggle Special minor  mode."
    ;; The initial value.
    :init-value nil
    ;; The indicator for the mode line.
    :lighter " mSpecial"
    ;; The group this mode is in.
    :group 'mygroup
    ;; The minor mode bindings.
    :keymap (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map (kbd "q") 'quit-window)
    map))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Special mode is a major mode, and you can only have one major mode active at a time. However, you can have an arbitrary number of minor modes active on top of the major mode, and the keymaps for the minor mode take precedence over the major mode. So I would suggest you put your temporary buffer into org mode, and also create a custom minor mode that has your key bindings set.

Comment: I tried this and defined a minor mode: `(define-minor-mode minor-special-mode :init-value nil :lighter " mSpecial" :keymap '((q . (quit-window))) :group 'mygroup)`

but when I hit `(C-h k q)` in my buffer after initializing this mode I see this:

`q runs the command org-self-insert-command (found in org-mode-map),`